# Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, bcs, external-content-type

I am trying to create a new external content type using SharePoint Designer, whenever I am trying to add WCF connection I get an error message as "*Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information*"

I am trying to add external content type to **SharePoint Online using SPD 2013**.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Close and re-open the SharePoint designer.
2. Clear SharePoint designer cache according to the article below.

[How to Clear Your SharePoint Designer 2010/2013 Cache.](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/how-to-clear-your-sharepoint-designer-20102013-cache/)

3. If the issue still exists, you could re-install the SharePoint designer.

Updated:
I suggest you could submit a service request like the picture below.

[image]

Comment: I tried, still same issue.

Comment: I have updated the reply.